# Creating map package with multiple page sizes within one MXD of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, software-recommendations, mxd

Are there any alternatives to an extension like MapLogic?

Comment: Do you mean 'map book' or 'map series'? A map package is a file that contains an mxd as well as the data that the mxd's layers reference, making it easy to share complete map documents with others.

Comment: Also, what version of ArcMap are you using? As far as I know, it is impossible to have multiple layouts within one mxd.

Comment: have a llok at this link: http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0702/dsmapbook1of2.html

Comment: What is the main requirement that you are trying to meet?  In any event I think you may be better to describe them in a question at [softwarerecs.se] but be warned that you need to read their help first because they are necessarily quite strict about how questions there are presented.

Answer (score 1):

For the price, Maplogic is a pretty good tool. However if you are on ArcGIS 10, mapbooks can be integrated in an MXD as cited in [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2010/08/27/what-s-new-in-10-the-good-ship-ds-mapbook-has-sailed-hello-data-driven-pages/).  However they're termed 'Data Driven Pages'.

Comment: I agree - use ArcPy to append PDF files that you have exported from MXDs with different page sizes

Answer (score 0):

the other way is you can use xtools pro 8 package for it,..

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to create map books with different scales for different pages, but I'm not sure that's what you mean.